# Verificar extensões de arquivos em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso verificar as extensões de todos os arquivos dentro de uma pasta, por exemplo:

```
Pasta:
    arquivo1.txt
    arquivo2.wav
    arquivo3.mp3
    arquivo4.mp3
    arquivo5.mp3
    arquivo6.txt

output:
txt, wav, mp3
```

alguém sabe como eu posso fazer para verificar a extensão destes arquivos? A lógica em si eu sei fazer, só preciso de um exemplo de como rodar a pasta pegando as extensões

Answer (score 6):

Pode utilizar a biblioteca `pathlib` para percorrer o diretório e obter o sufixo de cada arquivo:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('Pasta')

for filename in path.glob('*'):
    print(filename.suffix)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/listar-sufixos-diretorio)</sup>

A saída deste código para o exemplo dado seria:

```
.mp3
.mp3
.txt
.mp3
.txt
.wav
```

Para gerar um conjunto com os sufixos existentes, bastaria fazer:

```
suffixes = {filepath.suffix[1:] for filepath in path.glob('*')}
```

Assim `suffixes` seria `{'mp3', 'wav', 'txt'}`

Comment: Erro de digitação em: path = Pach('Pasta')

Comment: @ÉderGarcia Nem sei o que está falando :D hahah valeu.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer com o `pathlib`.

Este código retorna o `path` dos arquivos no local especificado.

```
import pathlib

path = list(pathlib.Path(".").glob("*"))

for nome_arquivo in path:

    print(nome_arquivo)
```

Comment: Não lembrava  do "suffix" que o Anderson utilizou na resposta dele. Vivendo e aprendendo!

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra forma seria usar `os.path.splitext()`, é uma função específica com a finalidade de separar uma extensão do nome do arquivo.

```
import os
for nome_arquivo in os.listdir(path):
    nome, extensao = os.path.splitext(nome_arquivo)
    print(extensao)
```

ou de forma mais resumida:

```
extensoes = {os.path.splitext(nomearq)[1] 
    for nomearq in os.listdir(path)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se isso ajudará alguém mais usei um módulo da biblioteca "os" chamado listdir que lista itens de um diretório de trabalho atual por padrão, mais se passar por parâmetro ele listará o diretório que foi passado, usei também uma estrtutura de repetição "for" que é execelente para mostrar itens de uma lista,e fatiei
com um manipulador de string rfind(x) que localiza o que for passado por parâmetro entre aspas, ele localizar em dados do tipo string.

```
from os import listdir
for x in listdir('Diretório'):
    print(x[x.rfind('.'):])
```